# Is there a way I can display the data on the same line?

Tags: python, file

I'm having trouble displaying information on the one line, I need it to display on one line and not separate lines. I want the variables `player_name`, `Outcome` and `max_guesses` to be displayed on one line. This is the code I have:

```py
f = open("Stats.txt", "a")    
f.write( str(player_name) + "\n")    
f.write( str(Outcome) + "\n")    
f.write( str(max_guesses) + "\n")    
f.close()    
f = open("Stats.txt", "r")  
print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

`'\n'` being a string literal, also using `with` you do not have to close the file in the end:

```
player_name = 'DirtyBit'
Outcome = 'Awesome'
max_guesses = '10'
with open("Stats.txt", "a") as fileObj:
    fileObj.write(player_name + ' ' + Outcome + ' ' + max_guesses + ' ')

with open("Stats.txt", "r") as fileRead:
    print(fileRead.read())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
DirtyBit Awesome 10
```